# Webstorm becomes extremely slow with node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, webstorm

Anyone knows what's the deal with this IDE?
I have been running it for a while, lately it has become very slow and unresponsive at times.
Gobbles up CPU even when just editing a bunch of js files.

Possibilities:
1. My code base is getting bigger...
2. I have several listeners which compile coffeescript and sass files in the background when these change.

In any case, I am very surprised (for the worse) that this is so slow. Would expect better from a developer of an IDE.

Anyone had this kind of problem before?
10x

Comment: most probably the problem comes from local node_modules size - indexing huge node_modules folders may take a while. We'll try to optimize node_modules parsing in the next release - please follow [WEB-11419](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11419) and related tickets for update

Comment: I don't experience any issue personally (don't use coffeescript and other compilers in the background). Feels that this question would be better expressed to Webstorm support than SO.

Comment: @llan lewin - ya i have also faced same issue with webstorm. it is such slowest editor ever i have found. then after i have started to use sublime text 3

Comment: I'm using Webstorm 2016.1 to develop an ionic2/angular2 app. Editing html files is extremely slow. Whereas ts files are fast. vm options set to use 2048m. I have 8gb.

Comment: Same as Guus -- almost constant 30% cpu usage on an 8core, 16GB machine!  Project is ionic2's simple sample app!

Comment: I used webstorm for 10 years, now its just bloatware I'm stuck with

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There are a couple performance tweaks you can apply to Webstorm to see if it improves your situation. When my colleagues and I found that Webstorm was slowing down these tweaks solved all our problems.

First things first, ensure your project is configured to utilise webstorm resources efficiently by excluding particular directories from a project. This will ensure the containing files are not indexed in memory and will not decrease performance when performing functions such as searching for files or text within files. Some examples of good candidates to exclude are the `node_modules` directory and compiled code directories.

If there are still performance issues, try the following:

If you are on Windows by default you would be using the 32-bit version. Navigate to the Webstorm directory (within program files) and you'll see `webstorm64.exe`, which will run Webstorm in 64-bit mode. (You might [need to install a proper 64-bits JDK](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) yourself then.)

The default VM options for IntelliJ IDEA may be not optimal when your project contains more than 10000 classes and developers often try to change the default options to minimize IntelliJ IDEA hangtime.

You can try bumping up the JVM memory limits for Webstorm. Open the VM options from the `IDE_HOME\bin\<product>[bits][.exe].vmoptions`. Initially try doubling the `Xms` and `Xmx`memory values.

Please note that very big Xmx and Xms values are not so good. In this case, GarbageCollector has to work with a big part of memory at a time and causes considerable hang-ups.

For more info on configuring JVM memory options you can refer to:

- Configuring IntelliJ IDEA VM options - http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/04/configuring-intellij-idea-vm-options/
- Configuring JVM options and platform properties - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: Thank you.Indeed I was running the default 32 bit version.

Comment: It was using 128M!!! and I have 8GB ram. I increased it to 2048m. It works super fast right now. thanks a lot

Comment: so choose "exclude directory" and making node_modules excluded will speed up indexing etc?

Comment: but doesnt that mess with syntax highlight etc WRT modules in node_modules..?

Comment: @AlexMills Sounds like overkill, you really want syntax highlighting for ALL your node modules? You can define syntax hi-lighting (amongst other features) for particular libraries using https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: ummm I guess that would be too much to ask and JS syntax highlighting is unreliable anyway

Comment: 'excluding particular directories from a project' worked really well.

Comment: You don't have to modify your installation folder anymore -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/tuning-webstorm.html

Comment: As for 64 bits: it seems that `Webstorm.bat` should select the 64 bits automatically, if it finds `\lib\amd64`. However, that's not present in my WebStorm's bundled JRE, though it is when installing Oracle's Java 8 manually. That batch file is not used by default; see JetBrains' [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) about how the 32 and 64 bits executables and the batch file search for a proper JDK; in my case the 64 bits version found a Java 6 in my `PATH`...

Comment: FYI I wrote a ticket to them to fix the 64-bit 32-bit thing: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24989

Comment: If you don't allow your node modules directory to be indexed, you more than likely won't be able to use intellisense to auto import.

Comment: Like Benno said, if you exclude node_modules you'll lose auto-import and I'm also noticing that I'm losing support for framework integrations (like Angular/AngularJS), so this doesn't seem like a viable solution.

Comment: nothing can fix this IDE -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61448/Long-term-user-webstorm-performance-has-gradually-gotten-worse-over-the-years-that-its-almost-unusable-in-a-2019-mbp

Answer (score 31):

You can now do it from UI.

[image]

These are my before-after. No problems with the garbage collector. Just multiplied all values by 4. Machine: 20Gb RAM, 4Ghz i7 CPU & SSD disk. With defaults it started to lag. Now no lag again.

Pasting as text for quick copy:

```
# custom WebStorm VM options
# Default:
# -Xms128m
# -Xmx750m
# -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
# -XX:+UseCompressedOops

-Xms512m
-Xmx3000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=960m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Answer (score 27):

I was dealing with a similar situation. CPU used to spike like crazy, and the IDE used to lag. Go to WebStorm preference and try disabling plugins that you do not need.

For instance, if your project uses SASS, what's the point of having LESS plugin running? Likewise, if your project uses Git, you don't need to have CVS or Perforce Integration.

[image: Disable Plugins that you don't need]

CPU still spikes when WebStorm is indexing my project files, but I usually just wait it out.

Comment: this helped a lot for me, very useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Stopping my TypeScript file watching significantly helped (both in the IDE settings menu and in `tsconfig.json`). I assume that once the project gets big enough, any changes force a large recompile. It's not ideal but it's something that worked for me and may work for others as well.